# I need to make sure that a plugin will not load until its dependency loads using RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, requirejs

I am using the jquery.validationEngine.js plugin. 
jqueryValidateEnglish cannot run unless jqueryValidateEngine is loaded first.

My jquery.wrapped.validationEnglish2.js is coded like the following:

```
        define(['jqueryValidateEngine'],function($){

         //Plugin Code here

        });
```

My jquery.wrapped.validationEngine2.js is coded like the following:

```
        define(['jquery'],function($){

         //Plugin Code here

        });
```

My homepage contains:

```
    <script src="/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/lib/require.js" data-main="/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/common2">
```

common2.js Contains:

```
        //Configure RequireJS

        require.config({
          baseUrl: "/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets",
          paths: {
            // The libraries we use
            jquery: [
                '/imagesrv/marketing/js/jquery.min'
            ],
            bootstrap: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/lib/bootstrap.wrapped.min',
            smartdevice: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/page/smart-device',
            eloquatag: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/page/eloqua-tag',
            main: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/page/main',
            startupkit: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/startup.wrapped.kit',
            jqueryuicus: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/jquery-wrapped.ui-1.10.3.custom.min',
            smoothscrl: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/jquery.smoothdivscroll.wrapped-1.3-min',
            genscript: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/gen-wrapped.menu.script',
            owlcarousel: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/owl.wrapped.carousel',
            placeholder: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/jquery.wrapped.placeholder',
            explorewhatshot: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/explorewhatshot.wrapped',
            kiblog: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/ki.wrapped.blog.script',
            jqueryValidateEnglish: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/jquery.wrapped.validationEnglish2',
            jqueryValidateEngine: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/jquery.wrapped.validationEngine2'

          } 

        });


require(['main', 'bootstrap', 'startupkit', 'eloquatag', 'owlcarousel',    'kiblog', 'jqueryuicus', 'jqueryValidateEnglish'], function($) {// Load up this  pages script, once the 'common' script has loaded
  console.log('jQuery and r.js have been loaded!');
});
```

But I keep getting the following error in the console when I run my page:
"$(...).validationEngine is not a function

[image: Console Screen Capture]

When I look under Network it shows that my wrapped plugins are loading but for some reason it seems like they must be loading out of order which is probably why I am getting the console error.

[image]

I am not sure what the issue is.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know requirejs, but looking at the code, could it be as simple as switching the order of `jqueryValidateEnglish` and `jqueryValidateEngine` in common2.js?

Comment: It won't work because jquery.wrapped.validationEnglish2.js depends on jquery.wrapped.validationEngine2.js

Comment: Right, but you have `jqueryValidateEnglish`, which refers to jquery.wrapped.validationEnglish2.js, **before** `jqueryValidateEngine`, which refers to jquery.wrapped.validationEngine2.js, in common2.js, so you're loading the dependent script first (at least that's what it looks like from the Network tab).

Comment: Thanks Mike I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

If jQuery loaded first , could utilize `$.holdReady()` , `$.when()`

```
    $.holdReady(true);

    var scripts = {
      bootstrap: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/lib/bootstrap.wrapped.min',
      smartdevice: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/page/smart-device',
      eloquatag: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/page/eloqua-tag',
      main: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/page/main',
      startupkit: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/startup.wrapped.kit',
      jqueryuicus: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/jquery-wrapped.ui-1.10.3.custom.min',
      smoothscrl: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/jquery.smoothdivscroll.wrapped-1.3-min',
      genscript: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/gen-wrapped.menu.script',
      owlcarousel: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/owl.wrapped.carousel',
      placeholder: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/jquery.wrapped.placeholder',
      explorewhatshot: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/explorewhatshot.wrapped',
      kiblog: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/ki.wrapped.blog.script',
      // load `jquery.wrapped.validationEngine2` before `jquery.wrapped.validationEnglish2`
      jqueryValidateEngine: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/jquery.wrapped.validationEngine2',
      jqueryValidateEnglish: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/jquery.wrapped.validationEnglish2'
    };

    var requests = $.when.apply($, $.map(scripts, function(url, name) {
      return $.getScript(url)
    }));

    requests.then(function() {
       $.holdReady(false);
    }, function(error) {
       console.log(error)
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      // do stuff when `scripts` loaded
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood the problem correctly, but from what I understood is that you are missing a declaration of dependency on your require.config, you are not telling require that it depends on anything, so, you need to make a change
to something like this:

```
require.config({
    //alias
    paths: {
      jqueryValidateEnglish: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/jquery.wrapped.validationEnglish2',
      jqueryValidateEngine: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/jquery.wrapped.validationEngine2'
    },

    //dependencies
    shim: {
      'jqueryValidateEngine': ['jqueryValidateEnglish']
    }
});
```

I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: Yes, I understand that but I belive that I am declaring the dependency because within the file jquery.wrapped.validationEnglish2  I am telling Require that jquery.wrapped.validationEnglish2 depends on jquery.wrapped.validationEngine2 by using:

    define(['jqueryValidateEngine'],function($){

     // Plugin Code

    });

Comment: oh, this is a common misconception, these are two different things, you have to declare it in both places, one for file inclusion (file order), and one for dependency injection (variable and function order), I hope this makes sense to you

Comment: Ok, I will take a look

Comment: @Jimmy Ignore what the answerer is telling you. You should not **ever** specify a `shim` for a module that uses `define`. The resulting behavior is undefined. `shim` is only for code that does *not* use `define` but must be made to work with RequireJS. Your initial comment on this answer is quite correct.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was thinking because I tried it and it didn't work